# Slow internet on Ubuntu while using Firefox but not Windows

Tags: 16.04, firefox, browser

About 1 in 5 times that I access a web site, Firefox shows a white screen and a little loading icon in the tab for 5-20 seconds, then the web page shows up. My machine is a dual boot and it does not happen in Windows 7.

This started after switching ISPs from AT&T to Xfinity and purchasing a new modem and router. Before I switched ISPs and equipment this did not occur.

I have a wired connection to the router.

Comment: If this is right after a fresh installation, it can be apt is trying to get the package list from servers. Just wait for a few minutes. That's a one-time process.

Comment: Firefox shows same behavior in Windows 10 and Ubuntu. I guess its a bug. Try other browser like Chrome.

Comment: Do you have other Windows machines on the network as well? Windows 10 is known to hog network. I've had same issue, but possibly applicable to Windows 7. What helps is switching your network settings within Windows to Metered Connection. See https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.howtogeek.com/249254/how-to-stop-windows-10-from-using-so-much-data/amp/

Comment: @dedunumax My installation is not fresh, it's a couple years old.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Right now this is the only computer on the local network.

Comment: Check if your MTU is correctly set on the router. For finding out the MTU use ping command.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Chromium and Opera on my Linux installation and neither of them lagged. It seems it was a recent update to Firefox for Linux that was causing the problem.

Comment: In that case try "refreshing" Firefox if you can.